# Run a For loop onLocationChanged

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an app for an individual project. I have a database of latitude and longitude coordinates with associated levels of radioactivity. The app checks the users location and checks the distance between them and the points in the database. If this distance is less than say 15 meters, it will trigger a warning light.

I was able to get the app to read in the database and store it in an arraylist of classes. I was also able to get the GPS to update location every 2 meters. I want to add a for loop in the onLocationChange method so that the app checks against the database but I am not sure how to do this... how can I pass the "dataPoints" arraylist to the locationlistener method so that the onLocationChange can access it?? Is this completed incorrect? I have included my code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
TextView txtLat;
String lat;
String provider;
protected String latitude,longitude; 
protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 2, mLocationListener);

//read in datapoints from text file in assets folder and store in class "radioactivityData" in arrayList "dataPoints"
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("combinedorderedData.txt")));
} catch (IOException e2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e2.printStackTrace();
}

//Define and initialize the ArrayList
ArrayList<radioactivityData> dataPoints = new ArrayList<radioactivityData>(); //The ArrayList stores strings

String inLine; //Buffer to store the current line
try {
    while ((inLine = reader.readLine()) != null) //Read line-by-line, until end of file
    {
        String[] parts = inLine.split("  ");
        radioactivityData rad = new radioactivityData();

        rad.setlatitude(Double.parseDouble(parts[0]));
        rad.setlongitude(Double.parseDouble(parts[1]));
        rad.setradioactivity(Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));
        dataPoints.add(rad);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} //We've finished reading the file      

}

//I think I just need to pass the dataPoints array to the LocationListener method... how? is this    wrong?
LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

    //Here I want to calculate the distance between current location and the data in the dataPoints array
    for(int i=0; i<dataPoints.size(); i++){
        if(getdistance(dataPoints.get(i).getlatitude(), dataPoints.get(i).getlongitude(), 
                location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())<15 && dataPoints.get(i).getradiation()>5000)
        {
            txtLat.setText("Turn on the green LED!");          
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            txtLat.setText("No radioactive areas nearby!");             
        }    
    }
}   

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","disable");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","enable");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("Latitude","status");
}


private double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2){

    double theta, dist;
    theta = lon1 - lon2;
    dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    dist = dist * 1.609344 * 1000;

    return (dist);
}

private double deg2rad(double deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180);
}

private double rad2deg(double rad) {
    return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
}
};
}
```

Here is the radioactivityData class in case that would be helpful

```
public class radioactivityData {
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private int radioactivity;


public double getlatitude()
{
    return latitude;
}

public void setlatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getlongitude()
{
    return longitude;
}

public void setlongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public int getradioactivity()
{
    return radioactivity;
}

public void setradioactivity(int radioactivity) {
    this.radioactivity = radioactivity;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from **onLocationChanged** call a method to which you will pass current location in that method itself get All Location with which you want to compare.

Comment: This worked. I also put the arrayList to the top of the file outside of the onCreate method.